# Android Studio: What does the blueprint area do? What benefit is it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I'm working through Android layout and I know there is this new(er) thing call Blueprint.   I'm wondering what the Blueprint view offers.

**What I've Tried**

**1. Added Button and Moved It Around Via Constraints**

I don't see really any difference between the two design views (normal and blueprint).

Oh, I did see one difference in the two views.
You only see the outlines of the controls if you are floating above the normal design view (**image 1** below).  If your cursor is not in the window you don't see them (**image 2** below).

Is that the difference?

[image: android studio design view float]
[image: android studio design view]

**2. Searched Google's Android Dev Site**

I could only find one small bit of information at : https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor

It said:

> the Blueprint view (only outlines for each view)

The blueprint takes up a lot of screen space and I'm wondering if that is all it offers (just outlines of controls)?

I can't see how that is more beneficial than just seeing the "outlines" in the normal design view by floating over view.

Does blueprint offer something additional that I'm not understanding?  Is there some other benefit?

Comment: It's.. a Blueprin; the same idea used by maps, schematics, etc. It takes away the visual complexity of a design, to the bare basic lines that make up for it, to be able to inspect, measure, etc. It's a convenient view for some cases (and faster in AS, since the rendering is just.. blue backgrounds), and it allows you to see what would otherwise be obstructed by visual noise. Chrisvin's answer points out a few good reasons for it. When you need it, you'll appreciate it, until then, it won't provide much help if your layouts are simple.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Good point about being faster (rendering) in AS (with more complex layouts).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

AFAIK there really isn't any 'huge' advantage to the blueprint view. It provides a wireframe view of your design.

There are a few cases where it comes in useful though, for example,

- If your `View` is invisible, it won't be seen in the preview but it will visible in the blueprint view.
- Overlapping views are more clearly visible and identifiable.
- It provides a more clutter-free view where the constraints and views are more immediately identifiable.
- It's also used to be useful for preview of components that are 'invisible' (for example, imageview who's src get set programmatically).
- Rendering the blueprint view is faster. (As pointed out by  Martin Marconcini in the comments)

Comment: Yeah, I think you are correct. And then when you float over the normal design view you see the outlines anyways.  Those 3 bullet items you provided are good definitive answers. I'll wait a bit and mark this as answer.

Comment: You're right, the normal design view shows outlines when you hover over them. But there are times when you come back to look at a layout after multiple days , you might forget where to hover.

Comment: It's just an addditional tool, as Martin Marconcini pointed out, you probably won't appreciate it until you need it.

Comment: The blueprint view is the only view I want to see because of the things you mentioned. Your opinion that there is no "huge" advantage (not understanding why you quoted "huge") is an opinion that I don't share.

Comment: You may use the `B` key on the keyboard to cycle between *only the design view*, *only the blueprint view*, or *both views* – or use the blue icon in the toolbar above (with the tooltip *“Select design surface (B)”*).

Answer (score -2):

Its shows you only how the view looks like